# Longitudinal analysis with high level of attrition

Tags: r, data-imputation, longitudinal-data-analysis

I have an initial dataset of 500 individuals at Time 1; 350 at Time 2; 150 at Time 3; 150 at Time 4.

It's a bit of a headscratcher for me to figure out how to deal with this high level of loss to follow up. Multiple imputations are completely out of the question - this level of loss to follow up is certainly not at random - so I was wondering if any of you had an idea to deal with this. Should I only keep the 150 who participated throughout all the waves?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on the model you may not have to drop anything.

Comment: @user2974951 could you expand on that please. Maybe an example.

Comment: Why don't you tell us a bit more about this data and what your research question is? Is this related to survival analysis?

Comment: @user2974951 It is a 3 year follow up of people who have been admitted at a hospital following a suicide attempt. We made multiple telephone follow ups in order to better unnderstand the fluctuating nature of suicidal ideations over time and also identify potential predictors of reattempt at index.

Comment: The reason being that your times seem to be fixed (1, 2, 3 and 4), however you could treat them as random or as a factor, that is transform your data into long format. Can you post some sample data?